# How to set accessibility path in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility

In Swift, there are many tools for keyboard navigation accessibility, but I am not able to find a lot of those same tools in SwiftUI. Mainly, I would like to set the shape of the accessibility path to have a custom shape. Is there a way to do this in SwiftUI? Is there some strategy for making up for the lack of capabilities in UIView that SwiftUI lacks?

I went through Apple's documentation but all the accessibility path resources are for Swift.